# get event list with optional parameters returns no event

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, optional-parameters

The problem is I know there are both recurrence and single events in my calendar but when I use below parameters to retrieve events between specific dates, the count of returned events is zero.

```
$optParams = array(
    'singleEvents' => FALSE,//I also made it true, but didn't work. 
    'timeMax' => date("c", strtotime($startDateStr)),
    'timeMin' => date("c", strtotime($endDateStr))
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
    echo "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
}
```

For **timeMax** parameter my value is **2016-05-10T10:19:54+02:00** and **timeMin** parameter is **2016-06-29T23:00:00+02:00**. I can see there are events between these dates. Where am I doing wrong at? I could find only [this example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php#step_3_set_up_the_sample) and the example is working except for shared calendars.

Comment: Please try this link to get events , you will get idea what is issue https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events#try_it

Comment: I can't get the events from there either. Is it because the calendar is shared calendar?

Comment: please enable "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0: " and you just require calendarId if your calendar is primary thn just write down 'primary' else you need calendar id first

Comment: Yes I did same things already. :)

Comment: I can see the events if I don't query with timeMax and timeMin values. But I couldn't understand what is wrong with  my timeMax and timeMin values.

Comment: :) that best way to find error to add your params into above link, i did same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111537/discussion-between-vipin-sharma-and-melomg).

Comment: I'm testing it with [this link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it) and giving 2016-05-10T10:19:54+02:00 and 2016-06-29T23:00:00+02:00 as parameters but I get no event. But I know there are events between these dates. I looked at **accessRole** and it's status is **owner**.

Answer (score 1):

You have the timeMin and timeMax swapped. Change the code to:

```
'timeMax' => date("c", strtotime($endDateStr)),
'timeMin' => date("c", strtotime($startDateStr))
```

The interval is (timeMin, timeMax) so what you had was very empty ;)